# Implement Acquire/Release model by using volatile in java8

Tags: java, java-8, volatile, jit, java-memory-model

In my case, I want to implement the `Acquire/Release` model in java8 with `volatile`.

So I write the code that uses a volatile shared variable `I` to guarantee the modifying of `MAP` could be seen by other threads.

```
public static volatile int I = 0;

public static final Map<String, String> MAP = new HashMap<>();

// run at Thread-1
public static void write(){
    MAP.put("test", "test");
    I++;                      // release
}

// run at Thead-2
public static void read(){
    int i = I;                // acquire
    MAP.get("test");          // want to see the modifying by write()
}
```

My question is that:

1. Is the code synchronize correctly?
2. Is it possible that JIT eliminates the unused local variable `i` so that the `acquire` operation is invalid?

Comment: Why not use a `ConcurrentHashMap` and remove the whole `volatile int I`?

Comment: Your can't do that with volatile only.

Comment: @Lino what I focused on is the semantic of volatile, the object MAP could be another class.

Comment: @梁雨生 `volatile` variables are *never* cached by a thread. But that doesn't mean that the access to `MAP` is then `synchronize`d across all threads. You'd have to do that yourselves

Comment: @Lino as the `happends-before order` say `If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y).` and `If an action x synchronizes-with a following action y, then we also have hb(x, y).`, the `I++` is synchronized with `int i = I;`, and `If hb(x, y) and hb(y, z), then hb(x, z).`.

Comment: Please check the following post about how acquire/release can be upgraded to sequential consistency (so volatile). https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/on-the-fence-with-dependencies/

Comment: @Lino volatile variables are cached. A volatile variable prevents certain compiler optimizations and it add specific CPU memory fences. But apart from that; there is no conceptual difference between a normal variable and a volatile variable on a hardware level. The cache coherence makes sure that variables in caches do not get out of sync.

Comment: @Lino The only way to prevent a variable getting cached is to use some form of non temporal loads/stores. But this is a completely different game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First note that `++` on a `volatile` variable is **not atomic**, hence, you can’t rely on its value in case of multiple updates.

As long as there is only a single update, it may be sufficient to check whether the update did happen, but it is crucial *to perform the check*. Otherwise, there is no guaranty that the (supposed to be *acquire*) volatile read is *subsequent* to the (supposed to be *release*) volatile update.

Just consider the following timing:

```
      Thread 1        Thread 2

    ┌            ┐    [ Read I    ]
    │ map update │    ┌           ┐    
    └            ┘    │ map query │
    [ Write I    ]    └           ┘
```

Here, the two threads use the map concurrently, which is hopelessly broken, while the *acquire* and *release* actions have no consequences, as the *acquire* is not *subsequent* to the *release*.

You can only rely on this relationship if you check the value you’ve read and proceed only when it is the expected value written by the other thread.

---

Since the whole construct would work only for a single update, you can use a `boolean` instead:

```java
private static volatile boolean I = false;

private static final Map<String, String> MAP = new HashMap<>();

// run at Thread-1
public static void write(){
    MAP.put("test", "test");
    I = true;                      // release
}

// run at Thead-2
public static void read(){
    if(I) {                // acquire
        MAP.get("test");          // want to see the modifying by write()
    }
}
```

You can not use this for more than one update, as the thread wanting to perform a second update must ensure not to start updating the map before all threads reading the map after the first update have completed. But this information is not available at all with this approach.

Comment: And how about the second question? Is it possible that the JIT eliminates `int i = I;`?

Comment: The JMM doesn’t tell what the JIT can do or not, rather it tells which outcomes are legal. Since the answer demonstrates that without checking the read value, there is a legal outcome where the volatile read has no effect, you can derive the conclusion that a JIT could eliminate a volatile read when the value is not used, as the outcome would be the same. Note that in theory the same applies if an optimizer could prove that there is no write to the variable. Then, the read also has no effect, so the JIT could eliminate it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you really really help many times, and the code I showed is just a sample that discusses the semantic of volatile and the behavior of JIT but not practical code, maybe this question will misleading someone(I receive a downvote...), so I decided to delete the question.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you confuse terminology. `volatile` in java offers sequential-consistency, while `release/acquire` semantics do not. You can think about it as `volatile` being stronger than `release/acquire`. You can read [the beginning of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65171886/double-check-locking-without-volatile-but-with-varhandle-release-acquire/65171887#65171887), to understand what a potential difference between the two is.

Then, there is this [subsequent word](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) in the documentation and it's meaning:

> A write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent read of that same field.

What this means is that a `ThreadA` has to *observe* that write to the `volatile` field that `ThreadB` did. That means you need to check if the write was seen:

```
boolean flag = ...

ThreadA: flag = true; // this is the "release"

ThreadB: if(flag) { .... } // this is the "acquire"
```

Only when `ThreadB` enters the `if statement` (that is when the acquire happened), can you guarantee that everything that happened *before* the write (`flag = true`) will be visible in the `if` clause.

You can achieve the same thing, via a cheaper way with `VarHandle::setRelease` and `VarHandle::getAcquire`, but be careful, as this offers less guarantees as `volatile`, specifically it does not [offer sequential consistency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65099212/1059372).

So your example is a bit flawed. You can simplify slightly your understanding of `release/acquire` by thinking that release is a *write* that a *reader* must observe, with special rules, like `volatile` or `VarHandle::setRelease/getAcquire`. You do not do neither of these. Your `I++` (besides not being atomic) is not *observed* by anyone else, your `int i = I` is not checked to see if the value was really written.